# How can I change an input placeholder text using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I am trying to change the content of an input placeholder content using CSS. I was able to do it in the desktop version by doing this.

```
.st-location-new:before {
    content: 'Routes';
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```
<label class="st-location-new">Where are you going</label>
```

In the mobile version I can't get to change the placeholder text by applying the same method but without any success. I was able to change the color and size of the font but not the content.

```
<input type="text" name="location_name" class="form-control" readonly="" placeholder="Where are you going?" id="dropdown-mobile-destination" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" value="">
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't support it anymore. You need to use HTML or JS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this JavaScript code and delete the label statement

```
document.getElementsByName('location_name')[0].placeholder='Routes';
```